# How can i run a propery in logic app for each only first run of the loop?

Tags: expression, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Is it possible to remove a property after the first run in the foreach loop, i want to remove the property "pickedQuantity".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove properties from an object you can use

removeProperty function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#removeProperty

But not sure how this is possible in your loop. If you always want to remove it after the first run, why not do the first "run" outside the loop, then loop the rest?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to add the property outside the foreach loop in order to have it only once. For instance here is the sample json I have taken

```
{
    "shipmentLines":
    [
        {
            "PART_NO":1,
            "WEB_ORDER_LINE_NUMBER":20,
            "WEB_ORDER_NUMBER":30
        },
        {
            "PART_NO":2,
            "WEB_ORDER_LINE_NUMBER":298,
            "WEB_ORDER_NUMBER":347
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Logic app where I'm storing the `Compose` content to an array variable and removing the pickedQuantity property and added after the foreach loop:-

[image]

Here is the Json code in my `Compose 2` Connector.

```
{
  "shipmentLines": [
    {
      "pickedQuantity": "1",
      "shipmentDetails": @{variables('SampleArray')}
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the output:-

[image]

The Final Compose output:-

```
{
  "shipmentLines": [
    {
      "pickedQuantity": "1",
      "shipmentDetails": [
        {
          "shipmentLines": [
            {
              "articleNo": "2",
              "customerOderNo": "347",
              "lineNumber": "298"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "shipmentLines": [
            {
              "articleNo": "1",
              "customerOderNo": "30",
              "lineNumber": "20"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```